# How to one way sync two folders on startup

Tags: cron, synchronization

I am trying to synchronize:

> /var/www/CI_MAIN/

according to the changes made in:

> /home/coco/workspace/CI_MAIN/
>   (PDT's workspace).

To do this, I entered
`sudo crontab -e` in the command line,
and I added the following line to the end of the opened file : 
 
`@reboot lsyncd -direct /home/cockroach/workspace/CI_TEST/ /var/www/CI_TEST/`

I have also given full privileges to both folders by using `sudo chmod -R 777`,
but here is no changes made when I use my browser to see the pages I make.  This method had been working previously, therfore I think there should be something I have not done yet. Could you help me to fix the problem? Thank you vary much in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When writing cron jobs you should use the absolute path to the binary, if you haven't already done a export of your PATH in crontab.

Find out where `lsyncd` is located with:

```
$ command -v lsyncd
```

Example output: `/bin/lsyncd`. Copy the output and replace `lsyncd` with the absolute path.